# Bazel and visibility of classes

Tags: intellij-idea, bazel, monorepo

I have a monorepo project with the structure

```
backend
|- jvm
    |- apps
        |- core-service
            |- api
               |- src
               |- BUILD.bazel
            |- app
               |- src
               |- BUILD.bazel
        |- post-service
            |- api
               |- src
               |- BUILD.bazel
            |- app
               |- src
               |- BUILD.bazel
        ...
    |- libs
        |-core
           |- src
           |- BUILD.bazel
        ...
    |- BUILD.bazel
|- .bazelproject
|- BUILD.bazel
```

I have an issue. For instance, if I have two classes with the same name in different services. When I use this class in a code (for example, in core-service), I can accidentally import the wrong class (from post-service). And I will understand this only when I run the build. Bu some reason, IDEA imported the wrong class, and everything is looking fine till I run the build.

Is it part of Bazel configuration or IDEA configuration?

Comment: `Bu some reason, IDEA imported the wrong class` - IDE imports the classes, based on the [module's dependencies list](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html). I.e. if the current module you are working in has a dependency on a module (or modules) with matching class - IDE will import this class from the [first module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#sort-dependencies) among the module's dependencies.

Comment: @Andrey, you are right. I see that I have only one module. Is there any way to split the big module into separate ones? Maybe some extra configs in bazel?